# How Can I space up the numbers in Y axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing an analysis for Nasdaq Comp index prices and using ggplot to visualise my data . I use investing for historical datas

I used the code below to visualise year-to-date index data first

```
plot5 <- ggplot(nasdaq.comp, aes(x=Date, y=Price, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Prices", 
       title = "Nasdaq Components Index Performance YTD")
```

and my graph is like

[image: this]

I want to space up the numbers in Y axis so i can see the numbers clearly there ,  how can i make it?

thanks in advance for your helps

Comment: Hi again, could you try the following `ggplot(nasdaq.comp, aes(x=Date, y=as.numeric(Price), group = 1)` as your ggplot call and see if it improves?

Comment: it works and looks better and lined up but now instead numbers between 6,000 to 9,000 now it gave numbers between 0-100 on Y axis of the graph. I need to have original numbers and they are American formatted like "6,678.9 " if thats make a difference

Comment: If you have thousand-separators like `,`, you could take them out by substituting them with empty characters: `as.numeric(gsub(",", "", your_variable))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I convert the Price column a numeric one with as numeric by mentioning gsubs like the code below , it works out well without any error.

```
plot5 <- ggplot(nasdaq.comp, aes(x=Date, y=as.numeric(gsub("," ,"",nasdaq.comp$Price)), group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Prices", 
       title = "Nasdaq Components Index Performance YTD")
```

thanks for helps all , case closed .